# ReactIntl.FormattedPlural Component to String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.

I used `ReactIntl.FormattedPlural` to format the plural.

```
<FormattedPlural
    value={10}
    one='message'
    other='messages'
/>
```

It works when I place this component in the `render()` function. However, I have a scenario that  I want to get the String and passed into a function.

Instead of Using `{value ==1 ? 'message' ： 'messages'}`, can I use `ReactIntl.FormattedPlural` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In any case, in the end you need to put it into the render.
Because the `FormattedPlural` is a component. To display it, you need to render it. It's how React works.

You can save it as variable:

```
const text = (<FormattedPlural value={10} one='message' other='messages' />)
```

For example if you have a condition and need to decide which string to render.
But in the end, the `text` should passed to the render to be displayed for user.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from `FormattedPlural` [implementation](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/blob/78d35580ccd31f143bc1f3884326ecfe234c6929/packages/react-intl/src/components/plural.tsx):

```
const { formatPlural } = useIntl()

// get the plural category ("one" or "other")
const pluralCategory = formatPlural(count);
const options = {
  one: "message",
  other: "messages",
}
const plural = options[pluralCategory as 'one'] || options.other;
```

See also: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api/#formatplural